# Request data from server when other response complete in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I requesting the server(written in Node.js) using "fetch-api" function of javascript. I want to make multiple request to the server When the user clicks a button.

Is there such a way in JavaScript ?
When the server responds. Then the second request Send.
And when second response come.
Third request send and so on...
Please help me . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please have a look at how to ask a question on SO. Then edit you question to follow the guidelines and then I have no doubt you will get the assistance that you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

the fetch function returns a `promise`.
you need to `await` it like so:

```js
await fetch('http://test.com/1');
await fetch('http://test.com/2');
await fetch('http://test.com/3');
```

you can also access the responses like so:

```
const res1 = await fetch('http://test.com/1');
const data1 = await res1.json();

if (data1.foo == '123') {
  await fetch('http://test.com/2');
  await fetch('http://test.com/3');
}
```